# python writing list to new line, zip,

Tags: python, numpy, zip

My code writes my data to a file and I have just introduced the zip function so now all of my code is in the correct order but it is all on the same line and the '\n' part isn't working to put it on a new line after each a. How would I write to the datafile so there each list in a a new line?

```
   noop=np.arange(1,2)
    for kil in noop:
            if kil < 10:
                kil = '0'+str(kil)
            else:
                kil = str(kil)
        datafile2=open(str(kil)+'tempppa.txt', 'w')
        e1=np.genfromtxt(str(kil)+'_temp.txt').T[0] 
        meane1=np.mean(e1)
        e2=np.genfromtxt(str(kil)+'_temp.txt').T[1] 
        meane2=np.mean(e2)
        E1=e1-meane1
        E2=e1-meane2
        phi=np.arctan2(E2,E1)
        a=[E1,E2, phi]  
        a=zip(*a)
        datafile2.write(str(a)+' \n')
        datafile2.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` returns a list.  `str` on a list will put it all on the same line.  Maybe something like:

```
datafile2.writelines(str(x)+'\n' for x in a)
```

will do what you want.  Alternatively, you can `str.join` the list and write the result:

```
datafile2.write('\n'.join(map(str,a)))
```